# ProgressBar on white background

Tags: android, progress-bar

The spinning ProgressBar doesn't "show up" on a white background because the spinner is colored white.  Does Android include any ProgressBar styles to contrast with a white background?  Or will I need to skin my own?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To change only one ProgressBar, use the Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse style on your ProgressBar:

```
<ProgressBar ... style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse" />
```

To change all of your app's ProgressBar's, use Theme.Light on your manifest:

```
<application ... android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">
```

Comment: Hmm.  Well, the issue is just in this one particular spot of my application.  I like the progress bar spinners to be white in all of the other places.

Comment: Hmm... I was using the style tag to make the ProgressBar the small style.  Is there a small inverse style?

Comment: Yes: Widget.ProgressBar.Small.Inverse